# If I have backed out of moving into my apartment, is my lease still binding/ am I entitled to a refund if my guarantor never signed the lease?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, rent

so I am 22 years old and from the state of New Hampshire. So I'm a recent college graduate and during the last 2 years, I have rented through the same leasing company with no problems. Fast forward to this past May I graduated and was planning on renting through the same company again and had signed the lease over the summer for a different apartment with the hopes of everything running smoothly. Keep in mind its a college leasing company so they do require a guarantor. I was planning on using the same guarantor as the previous years, but they did not support my move so they decided not to sign the lease this time around. Before I had known they weren't going to approve, I had paid this fall's semester in full ($4,000),on-time and before my move-in day. Due to a lack of job-security/COVID, I had to keep pushing forward my move-in date to the point that I decided to back out of my lease and not move as a whole. Also, I did not pay my security deposit and I did not pay for any renters insurance for the apartment yet/at all because of the uncertainty of when or if I was going to be able to move in. As well, in my lease, it says I am not allowed to move in without renters insurance. Therefore, I was wondering if I was entitled to any money that I had put forth because I did not have a guarantor sign my lease?

Comment: Did _you_ sign the lease?  What does it say about early termination?

Comment: Whether your guarantor signed or not only means the leaseholder can’t ask the guarantor for money, but has to ask you. Whether they have the right to be paid is completely unrelated.

Comment: Okay, well my lease states " The lease CANNOT be terminated prior to the lease end date unless the owner-approved replacement is found. The resident, prior to being released, if and when they find a replacement, will pay a $250 release fee. The resident prior to being release, will pay a $500 fee if the owner finds the replacement."

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, the lease is binding

**You** were required to get a guarantor and you didn't - that might allow the landlord to terminate the lease but it certainly doesn't allow you to.